# Delphi - get what files are opened by an application

Tags: delphi, winapi, file, process

How can I get the list of opened files by an application, using Delphi?
For example what files are opened by winword.exe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the Native API function [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can list all open handles from all processes.

try this example

```
program ListAllHandles;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  PSApi,
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

const
SystemHandleInformation       = $10;
STATUS_SUCCESS               = $00000000;
STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW        = $80000005;
STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH   = $C0000004;
DefaulBUFFERSIZE              = $100000;


type
 OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS = (ObjectBasicInformation,ObjectNameInformation,ObjectTypeInformation,ObjectAllTypesInformation,ObjectHandleInformation );

 SYSTEM_HANDLE=packed record
 uIdProcess:ULONG;
 ObjectType:UCHAR;
 Flags     :UCHAR;
 Handle    :Word;
 pObject   :Pointer;
 GrantedAccess:ACCESS_MASK;
 end;

 PSYSTEM_HANDLE      = ^SYSTEM_HANDLE;
 SYSTEM_HANDLE_ARRAY = Array[0..0] of SYSTEM_HANDLE;
 PSYSTEM_HANDLE_ARRAY= ^SYSTEM_HANDLE_ARRAY;

  SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION=packed record
 uCount:ULONG;
 Handles:SYSTEM_HANDLE_ARRAY;
 end;
 PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION=^SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

 TNtQuerySystemInformation=function (SystemInformationClass:DWORD; SystemInformation:pointer; SystemInformationLength:DWORD;  ReturnLength:PDWORD):THandle; stdcall;
 TNtQueryObject           =function (ObjectHandle:cardinal; ObjectInformationClass:OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS; ObjectInformation:pointer; Length:ULONG;ResultLength:PDWORD):THandle;stdcall;

 UNICODE_STRING=packed record
    Length       :Word;
    MaximumLength:Word;
    Buffer       :PWideChar;
 end;

 OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION=UNICODE_STRING;
 POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION=^OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;

Var
 NTQueryObject           :TNtQueryObject;
 NTQuerySystemInformation:TNTQuerySystemInformation;


function GetObjectInfo(hObject:cardinal; objInfoClass:OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS):LPWSTR;
var
 pObjectInfo:POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;
 HDummy     :THandle;
 dwSize     :DWORD;
begin
  Result:=nil;
  dwSize      := sizeof(OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION);
  pObjectInfo := AllocMem(dwSize);
  HDummy      := NTQueryObject(hObject, objInfoClass, pObjectInfo,dwSize, @dwSize);

  if((HDummy = STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) or (HDummy = STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)) then
    begin
   FreeMem(pObjectInfo);
   pObjectInfo := AllocMem(dwSize);
   HDummy      := NTQueryObject(hObject, objInfoClass, pObjectInfo,dwSize, @dwSize);
  end;

  if((HDummy >= STATUS_SUCCESS) and (pObjectInfo.Buffer <> nil)) then
  begin
   Result := AllocMem(pObjectInfo.Length + sizeof(WCHAR));
   CopyMemory(result, pObjectInfo.Buffer, pObjectInfo.Length);
  end;
  FreeMem(pObjectInfo);
end;

Procedure EnumerateOpenFiles();
var
 sDummy      : string;
 hProcess    : THandle;
 hObject     : THandle;
 ResultLength: DWORD;
 aBufferSize : DWORD;
 aIndex      : Integer;
 pHandleInfo : PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
 HDummy      : THandle;
 lpwsName    : PWideChar;
 lpwsType    : PWideChar;
 lpszProcess : PAnsiChar;
begin
    AbufferSize      := DefaulBUFFERSIZE;
  pHandleInfo      := AllocMem(AbufferSize);
  HDummy           := NTQuerySystemInformation(DWORD(SystemHandleInformation), pHandleInfo,AbufferSize, @ResultLength);  //Get the list of handles

  if(HDummy = STATUS_SUCCESS) then  //If no error continue
    begin

      for aIndex:=0 to pHandleInfo^.uCount-1 do   //iterate the list
      begin
    hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].uIdProcess);  //open the process to get aditional info
    if(hProcess <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then  //Check valid handle
        begin
     hObject := 0;
     if DuplicateHandle(hProcess, pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].Handle,GetCurrentProcess(), @hObject, STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED,FALSE, 0) then  //Get  a copy of the original handle
          begin
      lpwsName := GetObjectInfo(hObject, ObjectNameInformation); //Get the filename linked to the handle
      if (lpwsName <> nil)  then
            begin
       lpwsType    := GetObjectInfo(hObject, ObjectTypeInformation);
       lpszProcess := AllocMem(MAX_PATH);

       if GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0,lpszProcess, MAX_PATH)<>0 then  //get the name of the process
               sDummy:=ExtractFileName(lpszProcess)
              else
               sDummy:= 'System Process';

              Writeln('PID      ',pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].uIdProcess);
              Writeln('Handle   ',pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].Handle);
              Writeln('Process  ',sDummy);
              Writeln('FileName ',string(lpwsName));
              Writeln;

              FreeMem(lpwsName);
              FreeMem(lpwsType);
              FreeMem(lpszProcess);
      end;
      CloseHandle(hObject);
     end;
     CloseHandle(hProcess);
    end;
   end;
  end;
  FreeMem(pHandleInfo);

end;

begin
  try
    NTQueryObject            := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('NTDLL.DLL'), 'NtQueryObject');
    NTQuerySystemInformation := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('NTDLL.DLL'), 'NtQuerySystemInformation');
   if (@NTQuerySystemInformation<>nil) and (@NTQuerySystemInformation<>nil) then
    EnumerateOpenFiles();
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: The header files for the Native API are present in the Jedi ApiLib (JwaNative) (Jwa) as well as the rest of the Windows SDK this saves you from declaring them yourself as above. If you the Jedi ApiLib is new to you our blog is probably a good starting point (http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/)

Comment: Hi @Remko, I know the Jedi APILib, this is just a simple  example of the NtQuerySystemInformation API, without dependencies. ;)

Comment: Hi RRUZ. When I am running your code, as a result I get the file name line this: "FileName \BaseNamedObjects\CTF.Compart.MutexDefaultS-1-5-21-2000478354-606747145-1801674531-500". Am I missing something? I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The NtQuerySystemInformation API retrieve all of the handles in the system. This includes file handles, Mutex handles, Event handles. you you must check the pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].ObjectType field to determine the type of the handle.

Comment: @RRUZ, this code not works. Could fix please? **`NTQuerySystemInformation()`** not list any process.

Answer (score 2):

You could port [walkobjects.cpp](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=3577&PN=2) or run a [command line process that does it for you](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/system/processesmodules/article.php/c2827/) and parse it's output.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the MSDN page...
it said NtQuerySystemInformation() is an OS internal proc, 
and that we're not recommended to use it:

> The NtQuerySystemInformation function
>   and the structures that it returns are
>   internal to the operating system and
>   subject to change from one release of
>   Windows to another. To maintain the
>   compatibility of your application, it
>   is better to use the alternate
>   functions previously mentioned
>   instead.