# Get Process Information

Tags: c++, c, windows, process

Im using C++ and im trying to create a program similar to handle.exe from sysinternals.

Basically, i am getting the filename from the user, and I need to be able to display which process is locking the file.

Does anyone know where I can get this information from? I've tried using some process functions in winapi, but I cant figure out how to get this information,

Here is an example of what im trying to create:

http://www.kartmann.org/freeware/WhoSLocking/ReadMe.htm

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an undocumented option on [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the file handles for a process.  There is sample code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx).

Second sample (in Delphi) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575286/delphi-get-what-files-are-opened-by-an-application).

Comment: thanks for the anwer, could you please link the delphi code :P

Comment: It's on SO, I will look again.