# NTQueryObject - STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS error

Tags: file, delphi, winapi, process

when using the Delphi code provided as answer on this page,

[Delphi - get what files are opened by an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575286/delphi-get-what-files-are-opened-by-an-application)

I get nice results on Windows 8 but an error on XP 
in the provided function "`GetObjectInfo`" : 
`NTQueryObject` called at line 4 is returning `STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS` (3221225475).

It seems that the class `ObjectNameInformation` is not a valid info class.

I use Delphi 7.

```
program ListAllHandles;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  PSApi,
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

const
SystemHandleInformation       = $10;
STATUS_SUCCESS               = $00000000;
STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW        = $80000005;
STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH   = $C0000004;
DefaulBUFFERSIZE              = $100000;


type
 OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS = (ObjectBasicInformation,ObjectNameInformation,ObjectTypeInformation,ObjectAllTypesInformation,ObjectHandleInformation );

 SYSTEM_HANDLE=packed record
 uIdProcess:ULONG;
 ObjectType:UCHAR;
 Flags     :UCHAR;
 Handle    :Word;
 pObject   :Pointer;
 GrantedAccess:ACCESS_MASK;
 end;

 PSYSTEM_HANDLE      = ^SYSTEM_HANDLE;
 SYSTEM_HANDLE_ARRAY = Array[0..0] of SYSTEM_HANDLE;
 PSYSTEM_HANDLE_ARRAY= ^SYSTEM_HANDLE_ARRAY;

  SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION=packed record
 uCount:ULONG;
 Handles:SYSTEM_HANDLE_ARRAY;
 end;
 PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION=^SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

 TNtQuerySystemInformation=function (SystemInformationClass:DWORD; SystemInformation:pointer; SystemInformationLength:DWORD;  ReturnLength:PDWORD):THandle; stdcall;
 TNtQueryObject           =function (ObjectHandle:cardinal; ObjectInformationClass:OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS; ObjectInformation:pointer; Length:ULONG;ResultLength:PDWORD):THandle;stdcall;

 UNICODE_STRING=packed record
    Length       :Word;
    MaximumLength:Word;
    Buffer       :PWideChar;
 end;

 OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION=UNICODE_STRING;
 POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION=^OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;

Var
 NTQueryObject           :TNtQueryObject;
 NTQuerySystemInformation:TNTQuerySystemInformation;


function GetObjectInfo(hObject:cardinal; objInfoClass:OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS):LPWSTR;
var
 pObjectInfo:POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;
 HDummy     :THandle;
 dwSize     :DWORD;
begin
  Result:=nil;
  dwSize      := sizeof(OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION);
  pObjectInfo := AllocMem(dwSize);
  HDummy      := NTQueryObject(hObject, objInfoClass, pObjectInfo,dwSize, @dwSize);

  if((HDummy = STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) or (HDummy = STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)) then
    begin
   FreeMem(pObjectInfo);
   pObjectInfo := AllocMem(dwSize);
   HDummy      := NTQueryObject(hObject, objInfoClass, pObjectInfo,dwSize, @dwSize);
  end;

  if((HDummy >= STATUS_SUCCESS) and (pObjectInfo.Buffer <> nil)) then
  begin
   Result := AllocMem(pObjectInfo.Length + sizeof(WCHAR));
   CopyMemory(result, pObjectInfo.Buffer, pObjectInfo.Length);
  end;
  FreeMem(pObjectInfo);
end;

Procedure EnumerateOpenFiles();
var
 sDummy      : string;
 hProcess    : THandle;
 hObject     : THandle;
 ResultLength: DWORD;
 aBufferSize : DWORD;
 aIndex      : Integer;
 pHandleInfo : PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
 HDummy      : THandle;
 lpwsName    : PWideChar;
 lpwsType    : PWideChar;
 lpszProcess : PAnsiChar;
begin
    AbufferSize      := DefaulBUFFERSIZE;
  pHandleInfo      := AllocMem(AbufferSize);
  HDummy           := NTQuerySystemInformation(DWORD(SystemHandleInformation), pHandleInfo,AbufferSize, @ResultLength);  //Get the list of handles

  if(HDummy = STATUS_SUCCESS) then  //If no error continue
    begin

      for aIndex:=0 to pHandleInfo^.uCount-1 do   //iterate the list
      begin
    hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].uIdProcess);  //open the process to get aditional info
    if(hProcess <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then  //Check valid handle
        begin
     hObject := 0;
     if DuplicateHandle(hProcess, pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].Handle,GetCurrentProcess(), @hObject, STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED,FALSE, 0) then  //Get  a copy of the original handle
          begin
      lpwsName := GetObjectInfo(hObject, ObjectNameInformation); //Get the filename linked to the handle
      if (lpwsName <> nil)  then
            begin
       lpwsType    := GetObjectInfo(hObject, ObjectTypeInformation);
       lpszProcess := AllocMem(MAX_PATH);

       if GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0,lpszProcess, MAX_PATH)<>0 then  //get the name of the process
               sDummy:=ExtractFileName(lpszProcess)
              else
               sDummy:= 'System Process';

              Writeln('PID      ',pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].uIdProcess);
              Writeln('Handle   ',pHandleInfo.Handles[aIndex].Handle);
              Writeln('Process  ',sDummy);
              Writeln('FileName ',string(lpwsName));
              Writeln;

              FreeMem(lpwsName);
              FreeMem(lpwsType);
              FreeMem(lpszProcess);
      end;
      CloseHandle(hObject);
     end;
     CloseHandle(hProcess);
    end;
   end;
  end;
  FreeMem(pHandleInfo);
```

Any help ?

Comment: Provide an SSCCE please

Comment: [MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383(v=vs.85).aspx) that `NtQueryObject` only accepts `ObjectBasicInformation` or `ObjectTypeInformation`. It also says *"This function may be changed or removed from Windows without further notice"*, which is worrying.

Comment: Review the code if you want to make use of it. F.i. OpenProcess does not return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE when it fails.

Comment: Thanks Sertac for this info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your translation:

- In C an enum has a minimum size of 4 bytes, so you should set {$ENUMSIZE 4}
- Records should not be packed but aligned
- NtQueryObject doesn't return a handle but an NTSTATUS

My advise is to use the existing translations in the [Jedi Apilib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) since they are time tested. You need the JwaNative unit.

On my blog you can find a complete example on enumerating all handles: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2012/03/07/running-multiple-instances-of-lync-howto/